# How to get the metadata of Pub/Sub event in Spring Cloud function on Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I have created a simple Google Cloud Function with Spring Cloud Function library to get triggered on the arrival of the Pub/Sub message.  I followed the sample [function-sample-gcp-background](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-gcp-background/).  Whenever a message is triggered to the Pub/Sub, it gets printed from the Cloud Function as expected.

But I wonder how can I get the metadata of the Pub/Sub message in the Cloud Functon. The [Google Cloud Function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure) says that

> This metadata is accessible via the context object that is passed to
> your function when it is invoked.

How can I access this metadata (or the context object) in a Spring Cloud Function application?

UPDATE :-  Version `spring-cloud-function-adapter-gcp:3.1.2`

UPDATE 2:- I raised an issue in [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/695) and got the issue resolved. Thanks to Spring Cloud Function team.

Comment: Which metadata do you need?

Comment: Metadata which I need are the message publish time and message id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the issue resolved as per the advice from spring-cloud-function team.  The `Consumer` function needs to accept the parameter of type `Message<PubSubMessage>` instead of `PubSubMessage` to get the `Context` object.

```java
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<PubSubMessage>> pubSubFunction() {
        return message -> {
            // The PubSubMessage data field arrives as a base-64 encoded string and must be decoded.
            // See: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure

            PubSubMessage payload = message.getPayload();
            String decodedMessage = new String(
                    Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.getPayload().getData()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println("Hello!!! Received Pub/Sub message with data: " + decodedMessage);

                        // Print out timestamp and event id
            Context ctx = message.getHeaders().get("gcf_context", Context.class);
            System.out.println(ctx.eventId());
            System.out.println(ctx.timestamp());
        };
    }
```

Ref :- [github issue #695](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/695#issuecomment-832980003)

Answer (score 1):

When you use background function, the PubSub message and context are extracted and provided in the PubSub message. If you have a look to the PubSub object [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/7d053862ce98fb46a19ba978e88eb72046f303a9/spring-cloud-function-samples/function-sample-gcp-background/src/main/java/com/example/PubSubMessage.java#L20-L22); you have the Published Time and the Message ID embedded in it. You only have to use them!

Comment: The value of fields `messageId` and `publishTime` are `null`.   But I can see additional custom attributes are coming in the field `attributes`.